# Repl cannot run ursina in python

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to make a  3D game in repl.it with ursina however it did not seem to work.
Here is the following code...

```
from ursina import *

main = Ursina()
main.run()
```

Please note that `python3-xlib` is installed.

I get the following error...
[Why is this happening?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8LCZ.png)

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text. Provide the text instead.

Comment: I cant sorry no no never.

Answer (score 0):

that's because ursina doesn't work on replit, i used replit for 3 months, and when i tried to make a game in ursina, it gave me the same error as you, i use vs code instead, and it works